# How to define in HTML this page is same like one other?

Tags: html, seo, search-engine

I need to copy the content from one `HTML` page to another and it must be `SEO`-compatible. How can I say to the search engines: "Hi, this page is same like one other, here is the URL: www...." ?

I just checked the `base` HTML tag, but I think this is not that what I looking for.

I don't want to use HTTP headers, beacause this new files must be existing HTML files.

Any idea?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must use canonical links in `<head>` . For example:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/product.html"/>
```

You can reed [about it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_link_element)